# Cannot assign value of type 'UITableViewCell' to type '...Cell' error in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

```
let cellIdentifier = "ChampionThumbnailCell"

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ChampionThumbnailTableViewCell

if cell == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}

cell!.championNameLabel.text = championNames[indexPath.row]
cell!.championThumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: championThumbnail[indexPath.row])

return cell!
}
```

I want to use the above code to reuse UITableViewCell, but I got this error when build it.

It looks like thie: **Cannot assign value of type 'UITableViewCell' to type 'ChampionThumbnailTableViewCell?'**

Is there any solution could fix it?

(By the way, I'm not very good at English...)

Comment: What is `ChampionThumbnailTableViewCell`? You should provide the code for it.

Comment: `import UIKit

class ItemThumbnailCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ItemThumbnailImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ItemNameTextView: UITextView!
}`

Answer (score 2):

Change your method to this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


let cellIdentifier = "ChampionThumbnailCell"
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChampionThumbnailTableViewCell


cell.championNameLabel.text = championNames[indexPath.row]
cell.championThumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: championThumbnail[indexPath.row])

return cell
}
```

Notice in third line I am using as! instead of as? showing compiler that you aren't confused about your cell being nil.

But if it turns out that your cell is nil, **it should cause runtime error**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used these code before, but the reusable cell wasn't going well, I set the number of row in 129, and in iPhone6 plus there are 4 cells could see, if the reusable cell going well, I think it could only create 4 cells in order to show all of other cells. But in my case, it still create new cells until 129. sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Hey, i couldnt understand you properly. But, if you're saying that you set number of rows to 129, then the table will create 129 cell no matter what. I think you meant that your phone onlu shows 4 cells at a time, but that wouldn't make other 125 cells go lost. because you may wanna scroll... i am sorry if i didnt get you

Comment: Ok, maybe I should practice english before asking question, anyway thank you very much, have a nice day!

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help. But, your above comment was written in perfect English, just saying :) Good day!

Comment: oh, it is my pleasure to hear that, if you don't mind can i ask you one more question about collectionviewcell by facebook or some other chat app please?

Comment: sure, aksh500@gmail.com is my email, we can chat there, jsut send me a request, if not. let me know what your facebook is

Comment: Oh I'm vote your answer but my reputation is not enough to 15, I think it will change when I get 15. Well I will send you an email for my question. :)

Comment: @AkshanshThakur That method returns a non-optional, therefore the cell cannot be `nil`. If will crash if there is no registered class/nib for the given identifier though.